# NSURLRequest get pdf size

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, ios5

I have a UIWebview that loads a PDF with NSURLRequest. It will load the PDF, but if the pdf is too large the app crashes. I don't receive a memory warning. Is there a way to get the size of the PDF before I download it?

Here is how I am loading it:

```
NSURLRequest *currentRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myUrlString]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to user NSURLMutableRequest instead in case of downloading large file so you can obtain multi-part downloading. You can also use the method expectedContentLength of NSURLResponse to know the file length. Here is an example :

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response {

```
NSLog (@"%d", [response expectedContentLength]);
```

}

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

if (self.currentDownloadedFile)  {      
        [self.currentDownloadedFile seekToEndOfFile];
        [self.currentDownloadedFile writeData:data];
}
```

}

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection { 
// Close the file here
```

}

And force UIWebView open that downloaded file instead of downloading from un URL.